# How to initialize Graphics g?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I want to display a GameOver image in a pacman game after lives are over. But I call the paintGameOverScreen(Graphics g) and then I need to initialize g. Is there any other way to do this?

This is my Lives class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Lives{

private int lives;


public Lives() {
    lives = 1;
}

public void removeLife() {

        lives--;
        if(lives==0){
            System.out.println("END GAME");
            paintGameOverScreen(g);
            System.exit(0);
        }
}

public void paintGameOverScreen(Graphics g) {


            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src\image");
            Image image = i.getImage();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, 100,100,null);
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(5*20, 25*20, 100, 30);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    String result = "Lives: " + lives;
    g.drawString(result, 6*20, 26*20);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize g"? The g variable should already be initialized by AWT when it comes into the paint method.

Comment: Instead keep game state and paint according to it

Comment: If you want you could use an off screen buffer (such as a BufferedImage), paint to this and then re sync it with UI when you're ready

Comment: The line in your `removeLife()` method with the if-statement is redundant unless you can add lives. No need to check if lives is equivalent to 0 if you  just removed the only the life the player has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never call `paint()` or `paintComponent()` yourself, you always go through `repaint()` which will take care of setting up the appropriate `Graphics`

Just to show what @mKorbel is referring to:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Lives extends JPanel {
    private int lives;
    private ImageIcon gameOverImage;

    public Lives() {
        try {
            gameOverImage = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://imgup.motion-twin.com/dinorpg/0/f/77acf80b_989624.jpg"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lives = 5;
    }

    public void removeLife() {
        if (lives > 0) {
            lives--;
            System.out.println("Left lives: " + lives);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (lives > 0) {
            System.out.println("Still have " + lives + " lives");
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(5 * 20, 25 * 20, 100, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            String result = "Lives: " + lives;
            g.drawString(result, 6 * 20, 26 * 20);
        } else if (gameOverImage != null) {
            System.out.println("Game over");
            int x = (getWidth() - gameOverImage.getIconWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - gameOverImage.getIconHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(gameOverImage.getImage(), x, y, gameOverImage.getIconWidth(), gameOverImage.getIconHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame(Lives.class.getSimpleName());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final Lives lives = new Lives();
                frame.add(lives);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                // Dummy timer that reduces the lives every second. For demo purposes only of course
                Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        lives.removeLife();
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- for public `void paint(Graphics g)` { is there missed container,
- `JPanel` (in some cases `JComponent`)  could be container for todays Java
- have to use `paintComponent` instead of `paint()`
- inside `paintComponent` you can to flag for `paintGameOverScreen`, then there paint only `BufferedImage`
- prepare all `Objects` before, as `local variable`, do not load any `FileIO` (load images) inside `paint()`, `paintComponent()`

Comment: +1 some good advices sir :). Also OP must not forget `super.paintComponent(..)` call

Comment: For reference, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class InitializeGraphics
  {
        static BufferedImage buffer = null;
        static int height = 10;
        static int width = 10;
        static Graphics2D g2;

        public InitializeGraphics() {
                buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
                g2 = buffer.createGraphics();
                g2.fillOval(2, 2, 2, 2);
                g2.dispose();
        }
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                g.drawImage(buffer, x, y, width, height, null);
        }
        public Graphics2D getGraphics(){
                return g2;
        }
    }
```

Then somewhere:
    InitializeGraphics instance=new InitializeGraphics();
    Graphics2D gG2 = instance.getGraphics();